# Set std:cin to a string

Tags: c++, stream, cin

For ease of testing I wish to set Cin's input to a string I can hardcode.

For example,

```
std::cin("test1 \ntest2 \n");
std::string str1;
std::string str2;
getline(cin,str1);
getline(cin,str2);

std::cout << str1 << " -> " << str2 << endl;
```

Will read out:

```
test1 -> test2
```

Comment: You can't. Use `std::stringstream` instead.

Comment: If you're using linux/unix, using `|` on the shell would be worthwhile. So, you make a file with the strings and then do `cat myCinFile | myProgram`.

Comment: IMHO, a better correction is to use `std::istream` in your functions and pass either `std::stringstream" or "std::ifstream".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution IMO is to refactor your core code to a function that accepts a `std::istream` reference:

```
void work_with_input(std::istream& is) {
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
    getline(is,str1);
    getline(is,str2);

    std::cout << str1 << " -> " << str2 << endl;
}
```

And call for testing like:

```
std::istringstream iss("test1 \ntest2 \n");

work_with_input(iss);
```

and for production like:

```
work_with_input(cin);
```

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with @πάντα ῥεῖ that the *right* way to do this is by putting the code into a function and passing a parameter to it, it *is* also possible to do what you're asking for, using `rdbuf()`, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() { 
    std::istringstream in("test1 \ntest2 \n");

    // the "trick": tell `cin` to use `in`'s buffer:
    std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());

    // Now read from there:
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
    std::getline(std::cin, str1);
    std::getline(std::cin, str2);

    std::cout << str1 << " -> " << str2 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why so many people down-voted my question without knowing my specific use-case.  I really think redirecting the buffer for a quick test is the best way to go for me.

Comment: @user5797668 _"without knowing my specific use-case."_ Well, you maybe should have made your use case more clear in your question.

Comment: why does that matter?

Comment: and i did, it was "For ease of testing".