# Simulate command line input

Tags: c++, command-line

I want to simulate the introduction of this matrix for a HackerRank problem:

```
-9 -9 -9  1 1 1 
 0 -9  0  4 3 2
-9 -9 -9  1 2 3
 0  0  8  6 6 0
 0  0  0 -2 0 0
 0  0  1  2 4 0
```

How can I introduce it at compile time? My code is the following:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(6);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    arr[i].resize(6);

    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        cin >> arr[i][j];
    }

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

If possible I would prefer putting it outside the script but that `cin` obtains the values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set std:cin to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836016/set-stdcin-to-a-string)

Comment: Could it be included in a CMake file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, using a 2d array:

```
static const int test_data[6][6] =
{
    {-9 -9 -9  1 1 1 },
    { 0 -9  0  4 3 2 },
    {-9 -9 -9  1 2 3 },
    { 0  0  8  6 6 0 },
    { 0  0  0 -2 0 0 },
    { 0  0  1  2 4 0 },
};
```

So, rather than reading a number from the file, you read the data from the array.
Since the array is `static const`, it is defined at compile time.